# rpad doesn't work correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm doing a quite easy query (rpad):

```
SELECT 
RPAD(COMERCIO,40,' ')
FROM
SIEBEL.transacciones_acumulaciones_vm
WHERE     ESTADO  = 'Procesado'
AND NUMERO in ( '20232385',
'20225479', 
'20265516');
```

Output:

```
RESTAURANTE EL QUINC                    (lenght 40)
MC DONALD (lenght 9)
CARREFOUR EXPRESS-PA                    (lenght 40)
```

The main problem here is that Almost every 1.000.000 rows a literal from a specific column doesn't add that spaces.

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL? Either way I can guarantee you that the RPAD function is not your problem but rather the data that you are pulling back (otherwise if you are truly convinced it is the function then you should try and report this as a bug to the appropriate RDBMS vendor). Was the data originally loaded from a file? If so you might have picked up a space from a poorly handled header character every million rows your `COMERCIO` field that is throwing off your query. Trying using TRIM before using RPAD or go through and clean your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data probably has hidden characters. In unix, I look at a flat file using the `cat` command:

`$ cat -vet my-file` ... which displays the extended and non-printing characters. (For example, a 'tab' appears as a `^T` in the output.)

With oracle, here's one way of highlighting non-printing characters in a text field:

```
select replace(regexp_replace(COMERCIO,'[^[:print:]]', '!ACK!'),' ','.') as CAT_VET
from SIEBEL.transacciones_acumulaciones
where   ESTADO  = 'Procesado'
AND NUMERO in ( '20232385',
  '20225479', 
  '20265516');
```

... this will display the `COMERCIO` values, replacing any non-printing characters with the tag `!ACK!` any spaces with a period character.

This doesn't tell you which characters are the problem, but it does provide guidance/verification of the problem.